# Relationships in ArcGIS Server 9.3.1

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3, relationship-class, relates

I am working on a viewer in which I would like to show two related feature classes. If I select a feature of the first one, the related features of the second one should be selected too. 
I found a script on the Esri Resource Center:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/fl_query_related.html

My problem is that I can't get the relationship in de Mapserver. We run ArcGIS Server 9.3.1.

I created a "Relationship class" in the database. This relation works fine in ArcMap but when I make a service of it, it disappears. Secondly I created a "Relate" in ArcMap, which worked fine there, but disappeared in the service.

What is the solution to this problem? Is it possible to create a relationship with ArcGIS Server 9.3.1? The example server from the Resource Center uses ArcGIS SErver 10.

Answer (score 1):

For the Esri Web APIs, [native support for relates became available at v10.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/index.html)

It would not be impossible to do relates, such as via a JDBC connection, but this would not support any of the geodatabase behaviour like subtypes.